# Completely uninstall/restore Textmate 2

Tags: macos, editor, textmate

I accidentaly misconfigured the bundles settings of Textmate 2. Now I want to restore the default setting. I tried to remove the following directories:

```
rm -r /Library/Application\ Support/Textmate
rm /Library/Preferences/com.macromedia.*
```

I also use cleanmymac 2 to properly uninstall it.
But STILL everytime I reinstall textmate I always go back with my previous settings. Where the hell is it saving them? WHERE ARE THEY? Please help I'm desperate.

I probably will have to change text editor and it's pretty much like changing religion. :)

Answer (score 16):

Resurrecting this because I had the same problem, and it took me quite a while to figure out why my corrupted bundles kept reappearing.  You need to delete the following directories/files:

```
~/Library/Application Support/Textmate
~/Library/Application Support/Avian
~/Library/Preferences/com.macromates.*
~/Library/Caches/com.macromates.TextMate
```

I was really surprised that Textmate caches some bundles, but this solved my problem.  Hopefully it can help someone else in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Extending @kmacinnis answer: the best way to clean TextMate settings is to find everything matching in ~/Library and remove it totally:

```
find ~/Library -iregex ".*textmate.*"
```

and then

```
rm -rf {path}
```

Answer (score 0):

The custom settings for Textmate 2 are in /Library/Application Support/Avian/

Answer (score 0):

The following will work under MacOS 10.8 with TextMate Version 1.5.11 (1635):

```
cd ~/Library/Preferences
rm -rf com.macromates.textmate.*
```

Answer (score 0):

C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.3\plugins\Textmate folder and delete it . Worked for me :)